# Short exact sequences from the Euler sequence.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

I was reading an article in which the author said that the sequence 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    0 @>>>\Omega ^1_{\mathbb{P}^n} @>>> \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{\oplus n} @>>> \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}} @>>>0,\\
\end{CD}
can be obtained from the Euler sequence,
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
   0 @>>> \Omega ^1_{\mathbb{P}^n} @>>> \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{\oplus n+1} @>>> \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}} @>>>0.\\
\end{CD}
Could someone please explain how this is so?

Comment: Not as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

In the second sequence above, just take any $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)$ in the middle and its image in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and take the quotient to get the first exact sequence.